# How to share Guest VM's VPN Connection with Host - blocked at ping with VPN

Tags: networking, virtualbox, vpn

I'm trying to follow the answer of Kostas Filios in https://stackoverflow.com/a/68390615/8684705 but facing some issues

Everything is fine until step 8.

When VPN is OFF, I am able to ping guest network 192.168.56.x from host (and vice versa) but when the VPN is ON it is no more possible.
The network with host-only IP is still set correctly in guest while I see it in 'ipconfig' result, nothing changed only the VPN network added.

I also tried with firewall deactivated but the problem still remains :/

The VPN client I'm using is Cisco AnyConnect

Regards

Comment: Why don't you ask the author on SO?

Comment: I tried, but all my comment / questions where closed by SO admins :/

Comment: or maybe I can DM but don't know how to